# Can´t select first row in table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have table subject, when I try the query in adb shell the output is OK

SELECT * FROM subject;

The output is 10 rows...

When I do the same in Java/Android:

```
public ArrayList<Subject> getSubjectList() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();

    ArrayList<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<Subject>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM subject";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Subject subject = new Subject();
            subject.setId_subject(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            subject.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            subjects.add(subject);
        }
    }

    cursor.close();

    DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();

    return subjects;
}
```

The output is 9 rows... the first row with id 1 will not display, why?

Comment: Because you move to the **next** (`moveToNext()`) row immediately after moving on the **first** one (`moveToFirst()`)...

Comment: I added that as an answer, so you can accept it and remove the post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you move to the **next** (`moveToNext()`) row immediately after moving on the **first** one (`moveToFirst()`)...

What i normally do is something like this:

```
        if (cursor != null)
        {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    // ... 
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because on entering the if statement, you `moveToFirst()`, then on the first entry to the while loop, you `.moveToNext()`. Meaning you skip the first record.

So use a `do... while()` construct instead:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

    do {
        Subject subject = new Subject();
        subject.setId_subject(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        subject.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        subjects.add(subject);
    }while (cursor.moveToNext())
}
```

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html